# Why is there no init.pp in some Puppet modules?

Tags: puppet

I found that there are some Puppet modules without an `init.pp`. Why is this? What is the function of `init.pp` in Puppet modules?

Can Puppet locate a module without an `init.pp` manifest?

Comment: Where did you research and why didn't it help?

Comment: Just because Puppet is implemented in Ruby does not mean that questions about Puppet are about Ruby.  Usually, as in this case, they are not.  Tags edited.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thank your for your correction and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found there are some Puppet modules without init.pp. Why? What the
>   function of init.pp in Puppet?

The layout of manifest files inside a module's `manifests/` directory serves to allow the autoloader to map the module's class and defined type names to manifest files.  The manifest containing the definition of a class or defined type of the form `my_module::foo` is expected to be `my_module/manifests/foo.pp`, relative to some directory in the module path.

Many -- but not all -- modules have a class with the same name as the module.  For example, module `my_module` may have a class named `my_module`.  Such a class cannot go in `my_module/manifests/my_module.pp` because that's the location for `my_module::my_module`.  Instead, if a module has an eponymous class then its definition goes in `init.pp` in its manifests directory.  (Class names of the form `my_module::init` are disallowed to make room.)  On the other hand, if a module *does not* provide an eponymous class or defined type, then `init.pp` will not usefully contain anything; it can then be omitted.

The Puppet docs discuss [autoloading and manifest layout](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_namespaces.html#autoloader-behavior) in some detail.

> Can Puppet locate a module without init.pp?

Certainly.  Puppet does not rely on the presence of init.pp files to recognize modules.  Modules are defined by subdirectories of directories in the modulepath.

Comment: FYI I just edited his post and you are quoting it so they may be slightly off now.